# The method len(int) is undefined for the type Duplicate

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new to programming. I was writing the code of the following program:

> You have got a range of numbers between 1 to N, where one of the numbers is repeated. You need to write a program to find out the duplicate number.

Here is my code:

```
class Duplicate {
public void find(int arr[])
{int sum=0; int natural_sum=0; int d;

    for(int i=1; i<=arr.length;i++)
        {sum=sum+arr[i];
        }
    int len= arr.length;
    natural_sum=len(len+1)/2;
    d=sum-natural_sum;
    System.out.println(d);
    }

public static void main(String args[])
{
int []arr={1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7};
Duplicate ob=new Duplicate();
ob.find(arr);
}
}
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

> The method len(int) is undefined for the type Duplicate

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
natural_sum=len(len+1)/2;
```

to

```
natural_sum = len * (len + 1) / 2;
```

The way you wrote it, the *compiler* thinks that you are trying to call a method called `len()` which accepts an `int` argument.

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked :)

Comment: You're welcome @Aashi

Answer (score 1):

```
  int len= arr.length;
  natural_sum=len(len+1)/2;
```

`len` is a variable not a method.

for multiplication use

```
natural_sum= len * (len+1)/2;
```